# In the acme or at the acme?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have come across two acme sentences:

> He was **in** the acme of happiness.
>
> His fame was **at** its acme.

Which preposition do I use? What is the rule behind this?

Comment: [***At** the acme* is much more common than *in the acme*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+acme%2Cin+the+acme&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20acme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20acme%3B%2Cc0)  I'm not sure there is a "rule" for this - the exact preposition we use is often somewhat arbitrary.  But an acme is like a physical location, and one is usually *at* a physical location, unless you could be literally inside it.

Comment: Be aware that *acme* is not in common use, and many English speakers won't understand the idiom.  If anything, they might think you are referring to the [classic Roadrunner / Wile E Coyote cartoons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd_41tM6H2Y), as the Coyote often orders products from a company called "Acme".

Comment: @Andrew: That's an overstatement. Any basically literate English-speaker will understand *acme*. It's just not that recondite a word.

Comment: @Robusto I have never heard of the word *acme* until just now. (I at first thought it was a typo in place of *apex*.) I am more literate than the average bear, and so I find your *own* claim to be an overstatement. ;)

Comment: @stangdon - I think your comment explains why _in the acme of happiness_ could work; happiness can be thought of as an aura rather than a pinpoint location.

Comment: @JasonB - I was familiar with the word, but I agree that [other synonyms are more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+acme%2Cat+the+pinnacle%2C+at+the+zenith&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15) and therefore perhaps more readily understood.

Answer (score 3):

As I say in my comment, *acme* is not a common word, and I think relatively few English speakers will recognize what it means.

That being said, when I have seen it used, it's as a direct metaphor and not as synonym for a location.

> Her vocal skill was **the acme** of excellence.

This seems the most idiomatic (or at least the most elegant) to me, and not "at the acme" or "in the acme".  I would have written your two examples as something like:

> His was **the acme** of happiness.
>
> His name was **the acme** of fame.

I suppose if you forced me to pick, I would go with "at the acme" since it's a synonym for *peak* or *zenith*.

Side note: I expect more people will recognize "Acme" from [the classic Wile E. Coyote / Roadrunner cartoons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd_41tM6H2Y).  In the cartoons it's the recurring name of a company that delivers products which usually work, but rarely in the way that the Coyote intends.

Comment: I can not vote twice but +1 for the answer and +1 for mentioning Wile E. Coyote.